# Hello World Fails on Fresh Google Compute Account

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been trying to get a few apps working with google compute with no luck so I decided to try a simple "Hello World" app as suggested on the google app development console home page.   I believe I have followed it step by step (there are only 4 steps!) and It still doesn't work!

I set up a fresh google compute project named `testprojectname4` and the ID is `testprojectid4`.   When I try to launch a hello world app as per the instructions at https://console.developers.google.com/project/testprojectid4/start/appengine I get errors.

First I click the PHP option (bottom left square).

Then I downloaded the Google App SDK for PHP for windows (I'm on windows 7).

- Then I installed Python 2.7.
- Then I installed the Google App SDK for PHP.
- Then I downlodaed and unzipped the Hello World app from
  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-try-php/archive/master.zip to `d:/test` on my PC.
- Then I navigated to d:/test in a command prompt and ran "appcfg.py -A
  testprojectid4 update app.yaml"

  I got an error message saing appcfg.py is not recognized as an
  internal or external command....
- So I ran `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py"
  -A testprojectid4 update app.yaml`

Which gave me :

```
08:00 AM Host: appengine.google.com
08:00 AM Application: testprojectid4 (was: helloworld); version: 1
08:00 AM
Starting update of app: testprojectid4, version: 1
08:00 AM Getting current resource limits.
08:00 AM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'testprojectid4').
--- end server output ---
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is the hello world setup documentation missing steps ?

Answer (score 0):

The hello world setup steps are complete.

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project and ensure you have your project listed there with the correct ID.
- In your `app.yaml` file put in the correct ID:

  ```
  application: project-id-goes-here
  version: 1 
  runtime: php55 
  api_version: 1

  handlers:
  - url: /.*   
    script: helloworld.php
  ```